# my c# code works when i replace obj.SetActive(true) with Debug.Log("hit"); Why?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make it so when you get in a certain range of the GUI it activates. It was working perfectly when I was testing with Debug.Log("hit") however I changed it to obj.setActive and it stops working. I don't understand why this is?
here's the code:

```
private void Update()
{
    if (IsInRange())
    {
        canvas.SetActive(true);
    } else
    {
        canvas.SetActive(false);
    }

}

private bool IsInRange()
{
    origin = canvas.transform.position;
    direction = canvas.transform.forward;

    Collider[] hitColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(origin, range, playerLayer);
    foreach (var hitCollider in hitColliders)
    {
        if (hitCollider.name == player.name)
        {
            playerInRange = true;
            playerInRangeF1 = true;
        }
        else
        {
            count += 1;
        }
    }
    if (count != hitColliders.Length)
    {

        return true;
    } else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the object this script is attached to is enabled? If you put a Debug.Log in the Update function does it print anything?

Comment: @RetiredNinja yes both of those things check out. I also do not get any errors either way

Comment: When you say “obj.SetActive”, do you mean “canvas.SetActive”? And are you SURE you don’t see any errors? Note that you can’t turn errors display off in the Console by toggling the red icon in the top right of your Console window.

Comment: @MilanEgonVotrubec yes i do mean canvas.SetActive and yes I have turned errors, warning and comments on and off 100 times I've also showed friends that have experience in unity and no one understands whats happeing.

Comment: Where are you defining and resetting your `count` variable?

Comment: @MilanEgonVotrubec count is just defined as an integer. the count variable doesn't actually get reset anywhere yet this code still works while using Debug.Log?

Comment: @MilanEgonVotrubec the script is on an game object that is a child of the canvas I've been stuck on this for hours and I hate everything thanks for helping me answer my question!

Answer (score 1):

I have finally figured out the answer to my problem. The script I was running was a component of the game object I was trying to hide and show. When you hide a game object it obviously stops all of its components from working. All I had to do was place the script on an object that would not be hidden.